# How to model tables with different granularity?

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas, powerbi-desktop, ssas-tabular

I am working on a pbix that consumes from a SSAS cube:
I have a fact with Revenue; and dimensions: Date, Client, ClientType.

ClientType table:

[image]

For each Year, each customer has a Type.

In the pbix, a single-selection filter on FY will be included.

If FY 2021 is selected:

- Revenue for FY 2021 should be displayed.
- The Type for FY 2021 should be displayed.
- LY measures should be displayed under type from FY2021, not FY2020. (tricky part!!)

Likewise if FY 2020 is displayed, the LY  measures shall display under the type of FY 2020.

Shall I connect **Date** table with **ClientType** (even though they have different granularity)?  (Now I am doing this, and it isnt giving me the right results).